# How to echo in PHP the data sent with Ajax POST?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to get the type of carData with POST, but for some reasons this is not working, it doesn't echo it:

```
var carData = {type: "volvo"};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: carData,
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("Result " + data);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

My php code on the same page:

```
echo $_POST['type'];
```

Comment: your ajax call has no url option given?

Comment: Yeah, to where is it posting it?

Comment: Otherwise, check your console for errors.  Check your network console to see if the request is made and what the response is.  Add console logs to the calbacks to see which one fires.  Update the question with a more complete example of the source code that relates the script to the php script

Comment: You can make a div with some id. in success of ajax call, using javascript or jquery load the result into that Div#id.

Comment: It's not echoing it to the console you mean?